# Haskell Map Function type in detail

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
```

This definition is from Programming in Haskell by Hutton (p.62).

Looking at its type, I understand how the function takes first argument that is a function and second argument that is a list.

But does the type above become `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])?` so map takes function and returns a function that takes `[a]` and returns `[f x|x <- xs]?`

And Why is it `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` instead of `(a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] ?`

For example, the book uses `map(+1)[1,3,5,7]`

Can someone please explain this function in detail?

Comment: `a -> b` doesn't mean the two types *must* be different, just that they *can* be different.

Answer (score 5):

function return can be any other type, for example length on Strings.  The notation

```
(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

is equivalent to

```
(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

in general

```
a -> b -> c -> d
```

is equivalent to

```
a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

your function `(+1)` happens to be `Num a => a -> a` a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
You should be aware that the type of the function follows  the currying laws, so is right associative. This is why we avoid or remove the parenthesis in the type.

On the other hand you use different letters in the type of the function ([a],[b]) to refer that you are going to use a different type for input or output, where exactly they appear.